# How can i connect & configure a projector in redhat linux?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, projector

**SCenario:**

I like to **connect** and **configure** my projector in Red Hat Linux without using any external packages/third party tools

Example:

i like to configure basic projector properties where we usually find in **connect to projector in windows**

What i require?

Guide me how to connect & configure step by step?As am just a school student please provide it from basic steps,

how can i access system--->preferences--->monitors(As per answer posted) tab through commands?

Comment: You're question is rather ambiguious. What exactly do you want to do? are you using a gui desktop? What is the version of your OS? What type of connector you use? Be more precise if you don't wan't to be downvote (read the faq ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System` | `Preferences` | `Monitors`. From there you can configure any connected displays.

Comment: sir,i wish to know in additional how to access system--preferences--monitors tab through command since it might be helpful for learning

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question as "red hat". Are you actually using that distro? Not Fedora? Also, it is useful to let is know what Desktop Environment you are using. Anyway, it sounds like you are using gnome. In that case run:

```
gnome-display-properties
```

For MATE:

```
mate-display-properties
```

If you have an nvidia card and have the nvidia drivers installed:

```
nvidia-settings
```